# JavaScript Namespace objects : script include order

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I seem to run into a problem with name spacing in JavaScript.

I have separated my javascript `objects` into separate files.

Each file starts with namespace definition:

```
var MySystem = MySystem || {};
```

If I include the object, which calls some methods of the object that is included in the file after it - I get the TypeError saying that a given object does not exist.

Example of the problem I'm having:

**File 1** Url.js (included first in the html document):

```
var MySystem = MySystem || {};

MySystem.Url = {

    objHelper : MySystem.Helper,

    init : function() {

        "use strict"

        if (this.objHelper.isEmpty('string')) {

            throw new Error('The string is empty');

        }

    }

}
```

**File 2** Helper.js (included second in the html document):

```
var MySystem = MySystem || {};

MySystem.Helper = {

    isEmpty : function(thisValue) {

        "use strict"

        return (
            typeof thisValue === 'undefined' ||
            thisValue === false ||
            thisValue === null ||
            thisValue === ''
        );

    }

}
```

When called using `MySystem.Url.init();` I get:

```
TypeError: this.objHelper is undefined  
if (this.objHelper.isEmpty('string')) {
```

When I reverse the order of the included files - everything works fine.

This is obviously very simple example, but my system consists of many more `objects` - all of them in their own, separate file.

What's the best workaround for this problem?

Comment: `if (this.objHelper && this.objHelper.isEmpty('string'))`?

Comment: `objHelper : MySystem.Helper` can only work if `MySystem.Helper` is defined first, which is the case only when you reverse the order of the files.

Comment: And there's no really way around it? I believe that without namespaces - by simply using straight objects it would work just fine, but I like the code organised :(

Comment: Why would you want to use `MySystem.Url.objHelper` instead of simply `MySystem.Helper`?

Comment: Because it's a separate object - Url / Helper / Form / etc. Helper might be used in other objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You try to reinvent module system. Use require.js http://requirejs.org/

Comment: The OPs approach predates the existence of require.js…

Comment: Yes, it is true. But this approach suffers from problems that are solved in the require.js and more common in AMD, CommonJS and and finally in ES6 modules.